# Error when adding RxPresso to project

Tags: android, rx-java, android-espresso, rx-android, ui-testing

I got this error message when trying to add RxPresso(https://github.com/novoda/rxpresso/) to my project:

`Warning:Conflict with dependency 'io.reactivex:rxjava'. Resolved versions for app (1.1.9) and test app (1.0.14) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.`

I'm currently using rxjava 1.1.9. How can I add RxPresso in my project?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any problems with RxJava and Android Support Libraries version, go to your `app/build.gradle` file and in `dependencies` section paste:

```
androidTestCompile ('com.novoda:rxpresso:0.2.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'io.reactivex'
}
```

Comment: Nice one! Worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly tell Gradle which version to use, by adding into your `build.gradle` next snippet

```
configurations.all {
    // check dependency tree with gradlew :app:dependencies

    // avoid wildcard '+' dependencies used at 3rd libraries forcing them to exact version
    resolutionStrategy.force "io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9"
}
```

Comment: Both solutions (yours and from piotrek1543) worked for me. Thank you very much!